# storing comment by user

Tags: php

I am creating a site where it will have a member table where all user can comment among them. user 1 can comment in user 2 and viceverse.

```
    session_start();

include_once "scripts/connect.php"; 


$id = $_GET['category_id'];
$name = $_GET['name'];
$id2 = $_GET['ids'];
$toplinks = "";

if (isset($_SESSION['category_id'])) {
    // Put stored session variables into local php variable
    $userid = $_SESSION['category_id'];
    $username = $_SESSION['name'];
    $toplinks = '<a href="member_profile.php?id=' . $userid . '">' . $username .   '</a>   &bull; 
    <a href="member_account.php?id=' . $userid . '">My Account</a> &bull; 
    <a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>';

} else {
    $toplinks = '<a href="register.php">Register</a> &bull; <a    href="login.php">Login</a>';
}
```

the above script will check if session exist then connect to the database, and execute if session started. Now I want to store comment in user 1 profile from any other user and viceverse, how can I create a comment script form?

Comment: What are you using to store comments?

Comment: Do you just want to show a comment section which give provision for other to submit comments and then display the comments from different users to that profile.. What is the table structure of the comments table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have a table in your database that contains records for each user. You would then create a comments table in your database. Your comments table would have a field to store the id of who the comment was created by, as well as another field to store the id of whoever's profile the comment is posted on.

The form to create comments would contain the creator's id, the profile id, and the comment. The recieving PHP would put that information into the comments table in your database.

When you display a user's profile page, you would query the database for all comments that belong on that user's profile and display them.